# Python KeyboardInterrupt exception not working

Tags: python, python-3.x, keyboardinterrupt

I making multithreaded local ip scanner in python. I would like to add an option so that you can stop the scanner after pressing CTRL + C. I added keyboardinterrupt capture but it did not disable the script. Would someone help me write this?

My script:

```py
def ping(ip):
    if platform.system().lower() == 'windows':
        param = '-n'

    else:
        param = '-c'

    command = ['ping', param, '1', ip]
    if 'destination host unreachable' in str(subprocess.Popen(command, stdout = subprocess.PIPE).stdout.read().lower()):
        pass

    elif 'request timed out' in str(subprocess.Popen(command, stdout = subprocess.PIPE).stdout.read().lower()):
        pass

    else:
        with lock:
            try:
                host = socket.gethostbyaddr(ip)[0]

            except:
                host = 'No hostname'

            now = datetime.now()
            print(Back.LIGHTGREEN_EX + Fore.BLACK + now.strftime('[%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S]') + Style.RESET_ALL + Fore.LIGHTGREEN_EX + f' {host} | {ip} | Active')

def threader():
    while True:
        worker = q.get()
        ping(worker)
        q.task_done()


for x in range(60):
    t = threading.Thread(target = threader)
    t.daemon = True
    t.start()

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
s.connect(('8.8.8.8', 53))
ip = s.getsockname()[0]
s.close()

prefix = ip.split('.')
prefix.pop()

for worker in range(256):
    q.put('.'.join(prefix) + '.' + str(worker))

q.join()
print(Style.RESET_ALL, end = '')
```

Comment: there is no keyboardinterrupt  in you code

Comment: It's not there because I don't know where to put it

Comment: you write that you added it...

Comment: have you looked the code with debugger - there a lot of conditional logic in your function. Also you should specify the type of error in the exception (f.e. `except ValueError`), don't leave it just like that.

Comment: I showed the script without adding because everywhere I added it did not work.